# To inverse a sparse matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

I'm working with the sparse matrix, and I need to invert it. Actually, I'm looking for a some library, that can store and invert sparse matrixes. Does anyone knows some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do better than NIST:

http://math.nist.gov/sparselib++/

Comment: As far as I found, it was developed for Linux. Will it be working on Windows as well? Although can't find the function for matrix invert...

Comment: It's more common to use LU decomposition than full inversion, so that might explain why you don't find an invert function.  Most practitioners of linear algebra don't invert matricies.